# Windows: add python scripts folder to path

Tags: windows, python, path

On windows, I have some python scripts in a folder. How can I do to invoke a script without having to specify its full path? I tried adding the folder to the PATH environment variable but it's not working

Comment: If you add the folder to PYTHONPATH, you could import it from any script or interactive sessions. The first time you import it all of its statement will be executed (unless you have if __name__=='__main__' in your script)

Comment: I found a useful solution here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002291/how-to-run-a-python-script-portably-without-specifying-its-full-path